# validate object destructuring

Tags: javascript, eslint, jsdoc, ecmascript-2020

Let's assume we have two functions

```
/**
 * @typedef MyResponse
 * @property {Number} id - my awesome id
 * @property {Array<Number>} attributes - list of ids
 * */

/**
 * @return {Promise<MyResponse>}
 * */
function request0() {
  return Promise.resolve({id: 1, attributes: [1,2,3]});
}
```

and

```
(async function () {
  const { foo } = await request0(); // but it doesn't return foo, it returns id and attributes
  console.log(foo);
})();
```

Is it possible to highlight somehow that kind of errors? I tried to find something on eslint but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a problem here, you destruct the value from request0 which is a resolved promise containing those props

Comment: That depends on the level of JSDoc support of your editor. A static type checker like TypeScript would also catch it.

Comment: @asafel  the request0 returns id and attribute and it is documented through jsdoc notes. it doesn't return foo property

Comment: @str yes, kind of typescript but with jsdoc. it can work with accessing to a property of a plain object, but it doesn't work in destructuring case

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tusaeff.vscode-typescript-destructure-plugin - There is a plugin for VSCode, which will highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add `// @ts-check` in the begin of file without eslint.
Then, you could see your `foo` have red line.
But, you need to add it in every file with this way.
More detail in [Type checking JavaScript](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript) with vscode.

[image]

Comment: intelij idea also supports that kind of checking https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2019/09/using-typescript-to-check-your-javascript-code/